# Python string format with symbols in password

Tags: python, ssh, passwords, format

**Objective:** I want to SSH to a switch and execute a traceroute from the source to the destination.  The source and destination addresses and username and password for authentication on the switch are inputted by the user and stored in variables.  I'm using Python 2.7.10

**Working Code:**

```
from Exscript.util.start import start

from Exscript import Host, Account

from netaddr import *          

src_addr = raw_input('Enter source address for trace:   ')

SrcAddr = IPAddress(src_addr)     

dest_addr = raw_input('Enter destination address for trace: ')    

DesAddr = IPAddress(dest_addr)     

def do_something(job, host, conn):

    conn.execute('terminal length 0')
    conn.execute('tr {}'.format(DesAddr))

account1 = Account('username', 'password')  # <<<< THIS <<<<

host1 = Host('ssh://{}'.format(SrcAddr))

host1.set_account(account1)

start(account1, host1, do_something)
```

**Problem Code:**

```
from Exscript.util.start import start

from Exscript import Host, Account

from netaddr import *          

src_addr = raw_input('Enter source address for trace:   ')

SrcAddr = IPAddress(src_addr)       #function for IP address

dest_addr = raw_input('Enter destination address for trace: ')    

DesAddr = IPAddress(dest_addr)     #function for IP address

user_name = raw_input('Enter your CEC username:  ')

pswd = raw_input('Enter your password:  ')

def do_something(job, host, conn):

    conn.execute('terminal length 0')
    conn.execute('tr {}'.format(DesAddr))

account1 = Account('{}', '{}'.format(user_name, pswd))  # <<<< THIS <<<<

host1 = Host('ssh://{}'.format(SrcAddr))

host1.set_account(account1)

start(account1, host1, do_something)
```

I commented the focused code in the "working" and "problem" code sample.  Under the "working" sample, if I hard code the username and password it authenticates to the switch successfully.  Under the "problem" code sample, I'm trying to use format() so that the user can input credentials into variables.  But for some reason, it will just not authenticate using this method.  I'm suspecting it's because the password contain a '!' symbol, but I'm not sure.

**Summary**

Code that authenticates successfully

```
account1 = Account('username', 'password')
```

Code that does not authenticate

```
account1 = Account('{}', '{}'.format(user_name, pswd))
```

Comment: Your post doesn't contain a question. Often times posts with no explicit question result in confusing answers.  **Do you have a specific question?**

Comment: `Account('{}'.format(user_name), '{}'.format(pswd))`, although I don't know why you don't do `Account(user_name, pswd)`

Answer (score 0):

In this line from your question:

```
account1 = Account('{}', '{}'.format(user_name, pswd))
```

You are only formatting one of the strings. Try this:

```
account1 = Account('{}'.format(user_name), '{}'.format(pswd))
```

Or, equivalently and even more simply:

```
account1 = Account(user_name, pswd)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Both these suggestions worked:  account1 = Account(user_name, pswd)
account1 = Account(‘{}’.format(user_name), ‘{}’.format(pswd))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the format specifier correctly.

Try

```
account1 = Account("'{}','{}'".format(user_name,pswd))
```